# PInvoke from Fortran to C#

Tags: pinvoke, fortran

I want to import a function from a Fortran compiled library the signature of the function form for that I have access is in c:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_SUBLTdllTYPE)(double &,double *,double &,long &,char*,long );
```

My C# code is as follows:

```
//(long &,char*,char*,char*,long &,char*,long ,long ,long ,long );
    [DllImport(@"C:\Program Files\REFPROP\refprop.dll",
        CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto, 
        EntryPoint = "SETUPdll")
    ]
    public static extern void Setup([In] long nc,[In] 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder hfiles,
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder hfmix, 
        [In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder hrf, 
        [In,Out] long ierr, [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder              herr,long l1, long l2, long l3,long l4);
```

and the fortran definition is:

```
subroutine SETUP (nc,hfiles,hfmix,hrf,ierr,herr)
implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
implicit integer (i-k,m,n)
implicit logical (l)
c
cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: SETUP
c     dll_export SETUP
c
parameter (ncmax=20)        !max number of components in mixture
parameter (nrefmx=10)       !max number of fluids for transport ECS
parameter (n0=-ncmax-nrefmx,nx=ncmax)
parameter (nrf0=n0)     !lower limit for transport ref fluid arrays
parameter (nrefluids=4) ! numb
```

the problem is that I do not have access to a Fortran compiller and my knolege of fortran is almost zero.

When I call the function from C# code:

```
long ierr=0;
long i = 2;
StringBuilder herr=new StringBuilder("");
Setup(i, new StringBuilder("R410a.mix"), new StringBuilder("hmx.bnc"), new StringBuilder("DEF"), ierr, herr, refpropcharlength * ncmax, refpropcharlength,
            lengthofreference, errormessagelength);
```

I get the following error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've no idea about the strings in Fortran. However, your integers are wrong. In C on Windows, `long` is 32 bits. Use `int` in C# to match this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems incorrect to pass StringBuilder objects when you want a string. As a starting point I would try things like passing herr.ToString() or just build Strings to begin with instead of StringBuilder(s).

Comment: I have tried with string also but nothing is solved. I get an other error: <i>A call to PInvoke function 'RefPropTestNet!ConsoleApplication1.Program::Setup' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.</i>